# Using iPhone as a camera

Tags: iphone, camera, recording

I'm looking for a way by which I can see what I'm seeing while recording on another screen such as Macbook's screen or a monitor. For example, in this following image, I can turn the screen to myself to see myself while it is recording. Similarly, I wish to make the screen as Macbook's screen or a monitor while recording on my iPhone.

[image]

Comment: idk whether an iPhone can do this - I do it with my DSLR but it takes 200 bucks of software. The term you're looking for if you search is 'tether' - tethered shooting or tethering.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the term. Further, what about a program called "Reflector" by Squirrel ?

Comment: I've no idea. It's not something I've ever needed or ever envision needing. I have a DSLR to do this ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin is there any usage example of DSLR ??

Comment: That would be an entirely different question. Let's try not to turn this into a million comments on different topics. Stack Exchange doesn't work that way. https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/117693/57929

Answer (score 1):

I generally never tend to encourage to buy software not to advertise, however, on Iphone Epoc Cam HD(paid version) does perfectly its job. I've just bought it with somewhat hesitation since its free version seems, at first glance, really shlocky. After some tests with a lightning cable, sound and by setting resolution to 1920x1980, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The only native way to accomplish this is as follows (link to the article below):

- Connect your iPhone to your Mac
- Open Quicktime on your Mac
- Select File > New Movie Recording

In the main window, just to the right of the recording icon, there is a dropdown arrow; here is where you should see your iPhone listed as an input option.

[image: Capture iPhone screen with Quicktime]

That will then mirror your iPhone's display and from there you can choose to press record or just let Quicktime mirror the display.

The only drawback is that you cannot rotate the window on the Mac when you rotate your iPhone. Not a perfect solution, but it's something.

Otherwise, you'll have to go the third-party software route, see [Best Way to Mirror Your iPhone to a Mac](https://www.imobie.com/iphone-tips/mirror-iphone-screen-to-mac.htm).